# Can the frame border on a BarChart Legend be removed?

Tags: charts, wolfram-mathematica, bar-chart

I am creating an application for various kinds of plot/chart drawing in Mathematica. Ultimately it will have a GUI, but the first step is to get the code right, and simple enough for a GUI to manage. I am having difficulty setting legends to have no frame around them.

Here is a minimal example (with some options on `BarChart` already customised using `SetOptions`.

```
mydata = {4.5644, 5.546, 6.8674, 2.7688, 1.742, 5.3952, 4.3392, 4.5016, \
 3.7748, 1.838, 2.24, 0.693, 2.818, 4.9, 3.939, 3.459, 3.755, 4.475, \
 3.857, 3.215, 2.206, 2.206, 2.117, 3.403, 3.277, 3.761, 4.276, 2.559, \
 3.486, 4.778, 2.281, 2.865, 3.629, 4.916, 4.572, 5.244, 5.395, 2.865, \
 -0.524, 5.01, 4.401, 4.513, 4.54}

BarChart[mydata, 
 ChartStyle -> {Join[
  Table[RGBColor[0.5, 0.5, 0.95], {Length[mydata] - 3}], {Magenta,
   Magenta, Magenta}]}, PlotRange -> {-2, 8}, 
 ChartLegends -> {Join[
  Table[None, {Length[mydata] - 3}], {Placed[
   Style["Forecasts", FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 18], 
   Bottom]}]}, BarSpacing -> 0.4, 
 LegendAppearance ->  Directive[Background -> Red, 
   Frame -> None, ImageSize -> 15]]
```

And here is what I get:
[image]

Try as I might, I can't get rid of that border round the legend. You can see that `LegendAppearance` does nothing - I've tried a few other approaches to it, too.

I'm reticent to code up little rectangles by hand, because that will be very difficult to get right in the eventual GUI. `ChartLabels` won't work either, because that is already being used for date labels in the real version of the graph.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can temporarily, globally kill the frame by setting:

```
SetOptions[Legending`GridLegend, Legending`LegendContainer -> Identity]
```

To restore the default behavior, set:

```
SetOptions[Legending`GridLegend, Legending`LegendContainer -> Automatic]
```

Comment: +1: sorry, I'm home sick and only just got around to checking that it worked. It does work on v8, and it is the sort of thing I can put in the package as a default. Thank you!

Comment: Very, very interesting: `?Legending'*` (where that quote mark is a backquote) gives a whole bunch of undocumented bits and pieces.: AssembleLegendContainer ContourLegend Legend LegendImage LegendPane Legends BubbleScaleLegend CurveLegend LegendContainer LegendItemLayout LegendPosition LegendSize ColorGradientLegend GridLegend LegendHeading LegendLayout LegendReap LegendSow

Comment: @Verbeia thanks for confirming that it works, and I hope it is helpful.  Pardon *me* if I sounded impatient.  I was not.  Rather, a working solution usually gets at least one vote after eight hours, so I thought perhaps this undocumented option had been removed in version 8.  (BTW, I think you can embed the backtick by using double backticks for the code block.  Let me try:  ``?Legending`*``)

Comment: +1 for the backtick thing, and don't worry, the combination of timezone differences and a relatively small population of users means that sometimes nothing happens for a while. I find it hard to find questions that haven't already been answered really well, because most of the questions are posed when it's bedtime in Australia.

Answer (score 10):

I can't find any options to turn the frame off. The documentation for [LegendAppearance](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LegendAppearance.html) is fairly minimal and the styling of legends in general does not get much discussion (see [[2](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/howto/MakeALegendForMyCharts.html)] and links within).

The easiest solution I can think of is to manually modify the graphics. Charts with legends produce [Labeled](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Labeled.html) graphics objects. For a single legend, the `Labeled` object that is produced looks like `Labeled[Graphics[...], Framed[...], pos]`, so all you need to do is remove the `Framed` part. This could be done just be removing all `Framed` heads using a `ReplaceAll` (e.g. `BarChart[...] /. Framed -> Identity`), but maybe something more targeted would be safer.

```
mydata = {4.5644, 5.546, 6.8674, 2.7688, 1.742, 5.3952, 4.3392, 
   4.5016, 3.7748, 1.838, 2.24, 0.693, 2.818, 4.9, 3.939, 3.459, 
   3.755, 4.475, 3.857, 3.215, 2.206, 2.206, 2.117, 3.403, 3.277, 
   3.761, 4.276, 2.559, 3.486, 4.778, 2.281, 2.865, 3.629, 4.916, 
   4.572, 5.244, 5.395, 2.865, -0.524, 5.01, 4.401, 4.513, 4.54};

bc = BarChart[{Legended[Style[mydata[[;; -4]], Red], "Data"], 
   Legended[Style[mydata[[-3 ;;]], Blue], "Forecasts"]}, 
  PlotRange -> {-2, 8}, BarSpacing -> 0.4, LegendAppearance -> "Row"]
```

[image: with frame]

```
bc /. Labeled[g_, Framed[leg_], pos_] :> Labeled[g, leg, pos]
```

[image: with frame removed]

The above could also be produced using `Replace[bc, Framed[leg_] :> leg, {1}]`  or `MapAt[Apply[Identity, #] &, bc, 2]` or similar constructions. It wouldn't take much to modify the code if you have more labels or different types of graphics objects.

Comment: +1 I was about to suggest the same solution, but yours is more complete. The name `LegendAppearance` suggests more than it what it seems to do in practice.

Comment: +1 - thanks Simon, the second example (using `/. Labeled[g_, Framed[leg_], pos_] :> Labeled[g, leg, pos]`) does exactly what it should, even if the plot itself has a `Frame`. It will be interesting to work out the general case adn see if that can be done in a GUI.

Comment: @Simon  `InputForm[bc]`, possibly followed by `(InputForm[bc /. {Framed[legend_] :> legend}])[[1]]`, helps clarify why your solution works.  `[[1]]` removes the `InputForm[]` wrapper.

Comment: @David: Replacement rules (and `Map`, `Apply`, etc..) always act on the `FullForm` of an expression. But yes, I did use `InputForm[bc]` to see what was going on in order to construct my answer. @Sjoerd Thanks for the edit!

Comment: @Simon.  (Minor point).  Adding the option `FrameStyle-> None` also seems to work.  Your method can be used for quite subtle control of legend appearance.  For example: `bc /. Labeled[g_, Framed[leg_], pos_] :> 
  Labeled[g, 
   Framed[leg, FrameStyle -> None, RoundingRadius -> 10, 
    Background -> Yellow], pos].`  Thanks.

Comment: Both Simon's and @MrWizard's answers are "right" - and Simon's is more flexible. But the undocumented `Legending` options are exactly what I need to make this general for the whole application.

Answer (score 3):

Not as versatile as [Simon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/421225/simon)'s method given [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074209/can-the-frame-border-on-a-barchart-legend-be-removed/7075002#7075002), but nevertheless possibly worth posting. (I found this out while reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7477278/499167) question)

Using `Part`, where `bc` is as defined in Simon's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074209/can-the-frame-border-on-a-barchart-legend-be-removed/7075002#7075002):

```
bc[[2]] = bc[[2, 1]]; bc
```

giving

[image]