# Mathematica: Can I match the BarChart Legend to the stacked bars?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, bar-chart, mathematica-8

I would like to have the vertical arrangement of colors in stacked bars match the arrangement of colors in the chart legend. But no matter what I try, they don't match. Here's the situation

```
BarChart[{{5, 37, 56}, {22, 49, 28}, {31, 60, 10}},
   ChartLayout -> "Percentile",
   ChartLegends -> Placed[{"1-Volume", "2-Area", "3-Length"}, Right],
   ChartLabels -> {{"Before", "During", "After"}, None}]
```

[image: Chart1]

In the real-world example the legend has quite a few more entries (6), so it would be nice if the order of the legend colors matched the order in the bars.  I realize that I could set the `ChartLegends` to display at `Bottom`, but doesn't look good given the many legend entries.

Also, reversing the Legends list does not work as desired. The text of the legends was re-ordered, but the colors were not reordered (see below), so the legend captions no longer match the data in the chart.

Changing the order of the data (or the data and the legend items) does not work either.

Any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
BarChart[{{5, 37, 56}, {22, 49, 28}, {31, 60, 10}}, 
  ChartLayout -> "Percentile", 
  ChartLegends -> {"1-Volume", "2-Area", "3-Length"}, 
  ChartLabels -> {{"Before", "During", "After"}, None}] /. 
 Column[List[a : Grid[List[___]] ..]] :> Column[Reverse@List@a]
```

[image]

**Edit**

Remember to use `FullForm` when you want to mess up with Graphics/Chart/Plot internals

Comment: My goodness. I never would have thought to do that. So you changed the order of the legends after issuing the `BarChart` command?

Comment: @David Try the following `Barchart[ ....] // FullForm` and look at the Column command almost at the end :)

Comment: That's very enlightening. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Building on the nice answer given by [Belisarius](https://stackoverflow.com/users/353410/belisarius), an alternative method using `Part`

```
bc[[2,1,1,1]]= Reverse@bc[[2,1,1,1]];bc
```

This may be inferred from `FullForm` and

```
Position[bc, #, Infinity]& /@ {Framed[___],
Column[___],List[___,"1-Volume",___]}
```

or from any one of these, perhaps, and trial-and-error.

Although not part of the question, [Simon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/421225/simon)'s trick (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074209/can-the-frame-border-on-a-barchart-legend-be-removed/7075002#7075002)) may be used to further manipulate the legend.

```
bc/.Labeled[g_,Framed[leg_],pos_]:>
Labeled[g,Framed[leg,FrameStyle->Orange,RoundingRadius->10,
Background->LightYellow],pos]
```

for example, gives the following:

[image]

`Part` may also be used to remove the frame around the legend (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7074209/499167) question)
but [Simon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/421225/simon)'s method is much more versatile.

```
bc[[2]]=bc[[2,1]];bc
```

Comment: Nice work! I hadn't realized how deep into the innards of a chart one can go. My legend looks very large. I think I was in presentation mode; it affected the legend fontsize  by not the other fonts. BTW, it is a pleasure to push you over 2k.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`LegendContainer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074209/can-the-frame-border-on-a-barchart-legend-be-removed/7080536#7080536) for this.

```
SetOptions[Legending`GridLegend, 
  Legending`LegendContainer -> (Framed@MapAt[Reverse, #, {1, 1}] &)];

BarChart[{{5, 37, 56}, {22, 49, 28}, {31, 60, 10}}, 
 ChartLayout -> "Percentile", 
 ChartLegends -> {"1-Volume", "2-Area", "3-Length"}, 
 ChartLabels -> {{"Before", "During", "After"}, None}]
```

[image: same as belisarius' graph]

Comment: @David thank you.  See my other use of it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074209/can-the-frame-border-on-a-barchart-legend-be-removed/7080536#7080536).